# "The method x is ambiguous for the type" Mokito JUnit error

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have Main Class Like :-

```
class Main
{
    String str = "";
    protected String getStr(JavaRDD<String> obj)
    {
        return "Main";
    }   
}
class Child extends Main
{
    String str = "";
    protected String getStr(Dataset<Row> records )
    {
        return "Child";
    }   
}
//My test class :- 

class mainTest extends Child
{
    Child child;
    @Test
    public void testGetStr()
    {
        child = Mockito.mock(Child .class);
        Mockito.when(child.getStr(anyObject())).thenCallRealMethod();//Compilation Error
    }
}
```

The error I get is: 
`The method getStr(Dataset<Row>) is ambiguous for the type Child`

Please let me know the solution for this as im not authorized to change the *Main* and *Child* class. As when i mock *child class* the `getStr()` is not being called.

Comment: use partial mock maybe. then you can mock but for that particular method, use can call real method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Child` doesn't really override the `getStr` method of `Main`, because the method signature differs.

Therefore, the compiler can't tell which method actually should be invoked when calling `Child.getStr(anyObject())`. Should it be `getStr(Dataset<Row> records )` or should it be `getStr(JavaRDD<String> obj)`? The `anyObject` methods provides an object that will match **any** class.

I suggest either renaming one of the methods, or using `any(Dataset.class)` which will tell the compiler to use the method of `Child`, like this:

```
Mockito.when(child.getStr(any(Dataset.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Comment: *any* didnt help.

Comment: could you post the version with any(Dataset.class) ?

Comment: Mockito.any(Child.class).getStr(anyObject()).thenCallRealMethod();

Comment: oh, I see. It should replace the anyObject() method. I'll edit my post to include the whole line.